# Inserting values into the database brings wrong values

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have copied some code from the internet and modified it I kind of understand what it's doing but I can't get it to insert properly the records into the database.  I can't seem to get anything other than literally what I type in the values fields if I input "The name of a variable" then that's what I get out the other end. Once I get this to work it's finished.

The error I am getting is that the database is open/or /that there is a problem with the variables on the insert execute command line number.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\names.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            Conn.Close();//severl times connection has been open
            Conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(@"c:\\temp\\my123.xml");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
            DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
            dtCSV = ds.Tables[0];              
            cmd.Connection = Conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = Conn;
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            Conn.Open();

            for (int row = 0; row <= dtCSV.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col <= dtCSV.Columns.Count - 1; col++)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText= ("INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES (dtCSV.Rows ,dtCSV.Columns)");
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Error " + ex + "\n"; ;
    }
}
```

> Error System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not
>   closed. The connection's current state is open.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   WindowsFormsApp5.Form1.button9_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: When you use the using statement around a Connection, that connection instance is closed automatically when you exit from the using block. You don't need to close anything in the second button click

Comment: @Steve I cant understand the database still being open though even after a reboot now  @C Perkins can you help

Comment: What do you mean the _database still being open_ ? You create  a connection inside the using block. That connection is not open until you call Open on it. So no conn.Close as first line inside the using block and you don't need also the conn.Close at the end because the using block closes and disposes the connection when the ending curly brace is reached.

Comment: You are opening the connection twice, for the rest, your insert statement is looking a bit "funny", I am unsure what you expect will be the output of that statement, so when you get rid of the current error the next will come during cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). Also, `<= value - 1` == `< value` don't make it more complicated than it has to be

Comment: ... and also the cmd1 is not used anywhere here

Comment: @IcePicklle yes once iam back to bussines I said somthing wrong with the varibles

Comment: You've completely changed the code, making all the comments nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are calling `Open()` function on your connection object twice as seen in below code block. So essentially, you are trying to open the connection while the connection state is still `Open` and that's what the error saying exactly

```
        Conn.Open();      <--- Here
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(@"c:\\temp\\my123.xml");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
        DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
        dtCSV = ds.Tables[0];              
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.Connection = Conn;
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        Conn.Open();     <--- Here
```

As @Steve said `cmd1` is never used and looks like attached to same command text.

Moreover, your `INSERT` query never going to work the desired way cause you aren't actually substituting the values

```
"INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES (dtCSV.Rows ,dtCSV.Columns)"
```

You should meant it to be

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES ({0} ,{1})", dtCSV.Rows[row] ,dtCSV.Columns[col])
```

(Or) if you are using C#6 then you can just say

```
$"INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES ({dtCSV.Rows[row]} ,{dtCSV.Columns[col]})"
```

Comment: There are lots more goodies in that question, don't stop here ;)

Comment: @Icepickle, for all the goodies ... *codereview.stackexchange.com* :)

Comment: Well, I don't know, isn't that for [working coding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that should get a review? :)

Comment: when removed I get  "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: @Icepickle, right ... see edit in answer .. tried capturing most of but OP's posted code is flawed

Comment: Cool, any chance you could tell him what Parameters are? :) Showing the wrong way to correct a problem sounds like a new problem to me ;)

Comment: plus the iterators for the loops need to be used as indexes in the variables being used. Edit:(code fixed to reflect this)

Comment: @CharlesMay, you made me type it ... thought OP would understand the point ... Thanks

Comment: @Rahul I am using visual studio 2017, some of your lines dont compute $"INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES ({dtCSV.Rows[row]} ,{dtCSV.Columns[col]})" still says something wrong with varible

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\names.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            //Conn.Close();//severl times connection has been open
            Conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(@"c:\\temp\\my123.xml");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            //OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
            DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
            dtCSV = ds.Tables[0];
            cmd.Connection = Conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //cmd1.Connection = Conn;
            //cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //Conn.Open();

            for (int row = 0; row <= dtCSV.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                //for (int col = 0; col < dtCSV.Columns.Count - 1; col++)
                //{
                //    //cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES (dtCSV.Rows ,dtCSV.Columns)");
                //}
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                if (dtCSV.Columns.Count > 1)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(dtCSV.Rows[row][0].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(dtCSV.Rows[row][1].ToString());

                    cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO  tab1 ( field1, field2) VALUES (? , ?)");
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

            //Conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Error " + ex + "\n"; ;
    }
}
```

You can use this. I hope it help you.

Comment: Error System.InvalidCastException: The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type     on line       cmd.Parameters.Add(dtCSV.Rows[row][0].ToString()); thanks for the effort its what I was looking for  @Tien Nguyen

Comment: Error System.InvalidCastException: The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object value)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.Add(Object value)
@TienNguyen Iuse visual studio 2017